# font type and font size in python-docx

Tags: python, fonts, ms-word, python-docx

I am generating a MS Word document from a template using python-docx and I need a function that allows me to format text within the same paragraph.

I found this snippet in another topic that worked for me:

```
class Text:
    def __init__(self, text, bold=False, italic=False, color=None):
        self.text = text
        self.bold = bold
        self.italic = italic
        self.color = color

def add_text(textitems):
    p = doc.add_paragraph('')
    for t in textitems:
        r = p.add_run(t.text)
        if t.bold:
            r.bold = True
        if t.italic:
            r.italic = True
        if isinstance(t.color, RGBColor):
            r.font.color.rgb = t.color
```

This is called from another function this way:

```py
add_text([Text('This is an ', bold=False, italic=False, color=None),
          Text('example', bold=True, italic=False, color=RGBColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00))])
```

Now I want to implement font type and font size. Which is the best way to do it?

Solved this way:

```
class Text:
    def __init__(self, text, bold=False, italic=False, color=None, name=None, size=None):
        self.text = text
        self.bold = bold
        self.italic = italic
        self.color = color
        self.name = name
        self.size = size

def add_text(textitems):
    p = doc.add_paragraph('')
    for t in textitems:
        r = p.add_run(t.text)
        if t.bold:
            r.bold = True
        if t.italic:
            r.italic = True
        if isinstance(t.color, RGBColor):
            r.font.color.rgb = t.color
        if t.name:
            r.font.name = t.name
        if t.size:
            r.font.size = t.size
```

And calling it:

```
add_text([Text('This is an ', bold=False, italic=False, color=None, name='Calibri', size=Pt(12)), Text('example', bold=True, italic=False, color=RGBColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00), name='Calibri', size=Pt(12))])
```

Comment: Did you visit this: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html#apply-character-formatting

Comment: I did but I didn't know how to implement it in my code. Now I have tried another way and it works. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And use correct upper case letters please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work just fine. Note that it's probably cleaner to leave out keyword arguments that are not changing the default, like:

```
add_text(
    [
        Text('This is an '),
        Text('example', bold=True, color=RGBColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00))
    ]
)
```

Also, there is a `.from_string()` method on `RGBColor` that allows more compact expression, like:

```
Text('example', color="FF0000")
```

and `RGBColor.from_string(color)` in your `add_text()` function.